# Difficulties using ArrayFormula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, import, array-formulas, textjoin

I am trying to use ArrayFormula to populate row data. I have the following formula that work perfect when I drag down, however I am unable to figure out how I should adapt it to work with ArrayFormula.

Equation to populate data in each row where I changed U2 to U2:U for use with ArrayFormula:

`=IF(HOME!U2:U<>"",TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(LEFT(HOME!U2:U,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(HOME!U2:U,"/","#",4))-1),"//strong[@data-e2e='video-views']")),"")`

And this is the corresponding error when I use it with ArrayFormula ("Function FIND parameter 2 value should be non-empty.
"):

[image: 2nd equation error]

Appreciate any help I can get with this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IMPORTXML` is not supported under `ARRAYFORMULA`. you will need to stick to a per-row solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `FIND` formula in Google Sheets (you can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en)), needs a non-empty `text_to_search` parameter. In your case this parameter is obtained by using the `SUBSTITUTE` formula (you can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en)), which will return an empty value if it is unable to perform the substitution.

This can be solved by slightly modifying the `IF` statement at the beginning, with the objective to only return the `FIND` function if there is no empty value/error in the process. In the following example, I am doing it with the `IFERROR` function (you can read more about it [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)).

```
==ArrayFormula(IF(IFERROR(FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,"/","#")))<>"",FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1:A,"/","#")),"empty"))
```

with the following result:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. Could you provide an example mor in line with my formula specifically? Although the response above yours has mentioned that ArrayFormula does not work with ImportXML so I think we can throw in the towel.